# What are the assumptions of DBSCAN?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, clustering, dbscan

Does DBSCAN (Density-based spatial clustering of applications with noise) assume that the data follows a Gaussian distribution? and does the data need to be standardized (mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$)?

Comment: Maybe this related answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458767/how-to-scale-input-dbscan-in-scikit-learn

Comment: One of the advantages of DBSCAN is that it identifies irregularly shaped clusters. After running DBSCAN on a dataset, if you analyze the density function of each cluster, you will see that it is not necessarily Gaussian.